# comparing array with an observable MobX observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, observable, mobx

I have an observable array in my stores/index.js like this:

```
class Store {

    @observable order = [];

    fetchData = flow(function*() {
       try {
          const myData = yield backendService.retrieveData();

          if (myData.length > 0) {
             this.order = myData.map(element => {
                return element.id;
             });
          }
       } catch (error) { // error handling }
    });

    ...

}
```

I use this observable array in a component to compare it with another array, if they are not the same, I'll update the observable array through an action.

```
export default
@inject('store')
@observer
class myComponent extends React.Component {

     ...

     _closeModal() {
        const newOrder = this.state.data.map(element => {
           return element.id;
        });

        if (toJS(store.order) !== newOrder) {
           store.updateOrder(newOrder);
        }
     }
}
```

However the result of the comparison of the two arrays is wrong, even if I don't make any changes, `toJS(store.order) !== newOrder` still returns true. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when I console log the two arrays, they return exactly the same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, two arrays are strict equal, when both reference the same array. So `[] === []` returns false! because they are to different arrays.

You can change your code in this way:

```
if (JSON.stringify(toJS(store.order)) !== JSON.stringify(newOrder))
```

Comment: Is there alternate way without using string comparison? The current approach has few edge cases.